# Custom gradle plugin + access return value from method?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I've created a custom plugin to simply manage a `version.properties` file. All works fine, can execute gradle tasks and what not. The issue I'm running into is how to access the value returned from my task (to set the `version` variable at runtime) in my `build.gradle`.

Error:

```
Build file '/Users/yomateod/workspace/work/spring.black/tags/build.gradle' line: 35

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'tags'.
> Could not find method getCurrentVersion() for arguments [] on root project 'tags' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Line 34 and 35 in `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'versionest'
version = getCurrentVersion()
```

The task class:

```
package matthewdavis.io.plugins.versionest.tasks;

import matthewdavis.io.plugins.versionest.Version;
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class GetVersion extends DefaultTask {

    public static Version getCurrentVersionFromFile() throws IOException {

        String file = Files.readString(Path.of("version.properties"));

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file);

        matcher.find();

        Version version = new Version();

        if (matcher.groupCount() == 3) {

            version.setMajor(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)));
            version.setMinor(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2)));
            version.setPatch(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3)));

        } else {

            System.out.println("ERROR: invalid format for version.properties");
        }

        return version;

    }

    @TaskAction
    public String getCurrentVersion() throws IOException {

        Version version = getCurrentVersionFromFile();

        System.out.println(version);

        return version.getMajor() + "." + version.getMinor() + "." + version.getPatch();

    }

}
```

As you can see above I have the method `getCurrentVersion()` and running it via gradle works as expected:

```
$ gradle getCurrentVersion

> Configure project :
unspecified
> Task :getCurrentVersion
Version(major=0, minor=1, patch=0)
```

The full `build.gradle` is at https://github.com/spring-black/tags/blob/master/build.gradle#L35.

I declare my task at https://github.com/mateothegreat/gradle-plugin-versionest/blob/master/src/main/java/matthewdavis/io/plugins/versionest/VersionestPlugin.java#L12
and the task class is at https://github.com/mateothegreat/gradle-plugin-versionest/blob/master/src/main/java/matthewdavis/io/plugins/versionest/tasks/GetVersion.java.

I suspect I'm missing the proper way to call a tasks from the global scope of the `build.gradle`. Any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

Thanks ya'll!
-Matthew

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.. I needed to use an "extension" to expose my value to `build.gradle`:

```
project.getExtensions().create("versionest", VersionestExtension.class);
```

The extension class looks like:

```
public class VersionestExtension {

    public Version getVersion() throws IOException {

        return GetVersion.getCurrentVersionFromFile();

    }

}
```

`build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'versionest'
version = versionest.version.toString()
```

Running a test task to `println version`:

```
10:45:29 PM: Executing task 'compileJava'...

> Configure project :
0.1.0
```

For those that come across the same problem check out https://github.com/mateothegreat/gradle-plugin-versionest#setup